# Upload a file to server, process it, create a new file (txt file) and prompt for save

Tags: java, gwt

Ok, so far I know how to upload a file to server and process it(post method). I also know how to export a file from server (get method), but i can not figure out how to do it in the same servlet/action. I mean Upload a file, process it, create a txt(or other type of file), and then prompt the user to save the newly created file. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like that you have everything you need, you just need to combine the Upload and the Download.

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected final void doPost(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        String fileContent = "";

        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(req);
            //the items.get(0) is very error-prone, but good enough for this example 
            fileContent = IOUtils.toString(items.get(0).getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String fileName = "filename.txt";

        resp.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        out.write(fileContent.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    }

}
```

In my example I am using the Apache Commons FileUpload Library to read out the uploaded file, but you mentioned you already know how to archive this. But I included it to give a complete example with an Upload and a Download. Also lazy myself used the IOUtils to convert the `InputStream` of the uploaded File into a String.

This very basic example reads the content of the uploaded file and provides it to the client as a download. Therefore we write to the `OutputStream` of the response and set the relevant headers and the content type of the response.

### Additional things to know

If possible avoid creating a file with the result of your processing (on the server), because then you have to delete it after the download and this is very tricky.

Also this example **does not contain any authentication and has very (!) basic error handling**. You should always check that the request is valid and if not set the correct (`resp.sendError()`) http status codes (401,400,...). If your processing fails, you should also set the corresponding status code.